# What's the max level for the Chibi Robo amiibo?

Tags: amiibo, chibi-robo-zip-lash

Since every level seems to add new Chibi figures to get, it seems pointless to use the capsule machine until I have all of them unlocked.

My amiibo is currently gold at level 5 (after beating the game then and about half of the levels twice on top of that) and still leveling up, is 6 the max or are there even more levels?

Answer (score 1):

Yes six is the max level after which you can trade anymore earned points for gold using the amiibo, I know you should know this all by now, so this is for those that come across this question while googling